# how to change tab background?

Tags: android

I am working on a Android project. In my project I am using tab layout. It works fine but all tabs background is black and when I am selecting any tab ,that tabs background changes to light brown.Is it possible to give custom color?

my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

>

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

<TabWidget 
android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

></TabWidget>

<FrameLayout 
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

></FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>



</TabHost>
```

my java code is

```
   Resources res = getResources(); 
    TabHost tb=getTabHost();
    Intent i;
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;




    spec  = tb.newTabSpec("mee").setIndicator ("home").setContent(i);



    tb.addTab(spec);


    spec=tb.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("search").setContent(i);
    tb.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure :)
You should define and use styles. 
I suggest you to read here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html